# Password protection in .htaccess doesn't ask for password

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection

I'm trying to password protect a directory called 'test'.
This is what I've done so far (inside of the test directory)

File .htpasswd:

```
testuser:$apr1$qw60eHhx$14S4S2Mxx/26EgXqmb7Pw1
```

File .htaccess

```
<files /var/www/html/test>
#Protect Directory
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
</files>
```

When I call the directory in my browser, it doesn't ask for a password. Am I missing out on something? What could be the reason for that?

Comment: I'd say it should be `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` instead of `<files ..>...</files>` ...

Comment: @arkascha thank you, i changed that, but it still doesn't work

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file say when you restart the http server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just now realize that you are using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). In there blocks like `<Files ...>...</Files>` or `<Directory ...>...</Directory>` do not make much sense. And actually that is documented *and* pointed out in the http server's error log file. That leaves us with two options:

Either use the actual http server's host configuration (which should always be preferred if possible):

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html/test
<Directory /var/www/html/test>
  #Protect Directory
  AuthName "Dialog prompt"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/.htpasswd
  Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

This works, I re-checked with one of my own systems.

Or use a distributed configuration file (.htaccess), which means you need to grant altering access permissions in your http server's host configuration first using the `AllowOverride` directive. *And* you need to leave away the enclosing block which does not make any sense *within* that folder. So the actual ".htaccess" style file should just read:

```
#Protect Directory
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/test/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Both files need to be readable by the http server process. And the file permissions for the `.htpasswd` file require precision, again see the documentation for details. Also I would clearly recommend *not* to store such a file within the published documents folder, but *outside* of where the http server finds documents to publish. For obvious reasons...

---

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).